# How to disable a button hover based on a session variable?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, bootstrap-modal

I am making a form which is submitted in 3 stages. On each stage a new session variable will be set. Before any session variable was set the other 2 buttons should remain disabled on **mouseenter** and should enable on **mouseleave**.

Here is what I have tried till now but it's not woking:

```
session_start();   
if(isset($_SESSION['variable1']))
  echo "<style> .signal1{    background-color: #5cb85c !important;
                            }
                            </style>"; 

if(isset($_SESSION['variable2']))
  echo "<style> .signal2{    background-color: #5cb85c !important;
                            }
                            </style>";              
else{?>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $(".signal2").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    },  
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      });
        });
       </script>
    <?php }

if(isset($_SESSION['variable3']))
  echo "<style> .signal3{    background-color: #5cb85c !important;
                            }
                            </style>";
 else{?>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $(".signal3").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    },  
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      });
        });
       </script>
    <?php }

?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's not working? Is the JS code you wrote is not working as you want?

Comment: yes, those JS codes arenot working at all can you help me with that?

Comment: @himanshu you wrote an answer but it was not working and when i tried to paste my smaller version of code then something was blocking me to do that

Comment: yea but my solution did not work yea?

Comment: yes it wasn't.the button was disabled on **mouseenter** but it doesn't changed to **enable**

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).find(".fs").on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        },  
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="fs">yes!</button>
</body>
</html>`  here is the smaller version of my problem

Comment: if u want to know my form in detail [here is my whole form](https://github.com/ra-hulgupta/my-form/tree/new-form-3)